# how to get data attr into a table

Tags: r

I am reading in a sas data file would like to get attr. If I use haven, I looks like I can only keep "labels". If I use `read.sas7bdat`, it looks like I can get more attr.

[image]

Could any one tell me how I can get attr into a table? If the imported a SAS data into R as df, then I can get variables and labels into a table like below:

```
tibble(
  Variable = df %>% names(),
  Labels = df %>% map_chr(attr_getter("label"))
)
```

Any suggestion on how to get two more cols: `Length` and `type`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `attributes` to return a list of named attributes and `stack` it to a two column data.frame

```
lst1 <- lapply(attributes(df)$column.info, function(x) 
     stack(x[c("label", "length", "type")])[2:1])
out <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, id = seq_along(lst1), lst1))
```

-output

```
> head(out)
  id    ind              values
1  1  label    Study Identifier
2  1 length                 200
3  1   type           character
4  2  label Domain Abbreviation
5  2 length                   2
6  2   type           character
> tail(out)
   id    ind                  values
28 10  label Date/Time of Collection
29 10 length                      19
30 10   type               character
31 11  label Study Day of Collection
32 11 length                       8
33 11   type                 numeric
```

Comment: when I tried `attributes(df) `, I see sth `$column.info[[2]]$type`. To include both type and length, how should we modify the codes in your upper part?

Comment: I got `Show in New WindowClear OutputExpand/Collapse Output
Error in setNames(stack(attributes(df$column.info[c("label", "length",  : 
  argument "nm" is missing, with no default`

Comment: I think you have a `)` missing after the `sas7bdat`.  My code uses `attributes(df)$column.info`

Comment: Can you show the `dput(attributes(df))`

Comment: @Stataq it is a list of list.  So, you may need to have an `id` to identify each attrribute.  I updated the post

Comment: Will it be possible to get `Labels` if i used `read.sas7bdat` to read data?,  for `haven`, I can do `Labels = df %>% map_chr(attr_getter("label"))`

Comment: @Stataq Can you update with `dput(head(df, 5))` so that i can test it

Comment: @Stataq the example in `read_sas` in `haven` is not the similar attribute as yours

Comment: Is `id` in your output just the VARNUM? That is the sequence number (counting from 1 like normal people) that the variables are in the SAS dataset?